# onClick move arrow to selected bullet point - best approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a simple menu with 8 selections. When an item is selected I want the pointer/arrow to show which one is selected (by appearing next to the selection).

I have simple logic that works out the Y position of both the arrow and the bullet points (in an array). and I have a simple if clicked statement however I am not sure the approach for the next part.

I want to say; if the bulletpoint is clicked, arrow position y = the selected bullet point. What would be the best way to do this in javascript? I realise this is probably a simple question but I am learning!

```
$(".menuitem").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('clicked')) {
      $(".menuitem").addClass("active");
      // active-arrow pos Y = menuitem pos Y.
      // $a = this.$snapPoints;
    } else {
      $(".menuitem").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

here is the full version of what I have so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpLdyz?editors=1010

Massive thanks if anyone can help me to understand the best way to achieve this!

John

Comment: You should be assigning all items in your list with a unique id inside the tag. Then listen for a click on the className, get the id and move the arrow. You don't want to be looking at the position of the click in terms of position x,y when you don't need to.

Comment: I cloned your codpen and made it work, the arrows are a weird size though:  https://codepen.io/steveoneb/pen/PEXPYm?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

You can use css. If element which you want to mark with arrow is some input type, then you can even use :focus and not use js altogether.

```js
$('.menuitem').on('click', function(){
    
    $('.active').removeClass('active'); // remove old active
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add new active
    
});
```

```css
.menuitem {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.active::before {
    content: '>';
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menuitem">foo 1</div>
<div class="menuitem">bar 2</div>
<div class="menuitem">til 3</div>
<div class="menuitem">der 4</div>
```

With animation:

```js
$('.menuitem').on('click', function(){
    
    $('.arrow').css({'top':$(this).offset().top}); 
    
});

$('.menuitem').first().click();
```

```css
.menuitem {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.arrow {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: top 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="arrow">&gt;</div>

<div class="menuitem">foo 1</div>
<div class="menuitem">bar 2</div>
<div class="menuitem">til 3</div>
<div class="menuitem">der 4</div>
```